# facebook sharer - wrong link / share home not page where share button is

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I want to use a Facebook share button on a page in my website, but when I use the code on the Facebook documentation, the link shared is the link of the home of my website, not the link of the page where the share button is.

How can I change that?

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `share` button is not on Your home page?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I have the Twitter share button there too, and I don't have any problem with the Twitter share button.

Comment: Plus if I do that: <script type="text/javascript">console.log(location.href);</script>, I have the correct link of my page

Comment: Sorry, I realized the link shared is correct! It's what appears below the box where you add your comment which indicates the homepage and show an image from the homepage...